# Multiple annotation color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

i have a map with multiple annotation on it. i was able to show the first and the last annotations. i want to give each annotation a different color.

here is my code of how to insert my annotations

```
if(i<1 || i >object.count-2)            
{    
        MyAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];                        
        myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
        myAnnotation1.title=DEVNAME;
        myAnnotation1.subtitle=it.address;                        
        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];                        
        [annotations addObject:myAnnotation1];                             
}
```

the if condition is reading the index of the array to only drop the first and last annotation.

and here is how do i drop the pins on the map...

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
    (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)  
    {

        static NSString* MyAnnotationIdentifier = @"MyAnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                               initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MyAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;



       UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        return customPinView;
    }
    else
    {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
  }
```

how to different annotations color?

Comment: So u tried the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use MKAnnotationView class and set a custom image for each pin:

```
MKAnnotationView *customPinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin1.png"];
.
.
.
```

instead of using images from your app bundle, you might need to programmatically build your UIImage so you can achieve unique colors, this is up to you.

Furthermore, you can set a value on your annotation to help identify which annotation gets which image.  You'll subclass MKAnnotation to add this integer property called pinNumber.

myAnnotation.pinNumber = 2;

```
customPinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pin%d.png",annotation.pinNumber]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is of course not going to work as except for the first and last pin, for rest of the pins, the `else` part of the code will execute.

So there the `MKPinAnnotationView *pinView` will be `nil`. So the annotation with no memory allocated, can not change color!!! :-)

You must `alloc`, `init` the `MKPinAnnotationView *pinView` for else part somewhere according to your requirement.

Comment: u mean pinview=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init];
i tried this and gave me an exception error...

Comment: here is what did i try...
i<1 is the fist annotation, i>si-2 is the last one, else is the middle annotations.
these were written in the mapView method



if(i<1  )
        {  
    pinview=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init];            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple; 
            
        }
        else if(i >si-2)
        {pinview=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init];            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
           
        }
        else {
pinview=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] init];            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;             
        }

Comment: I think you should alloc init the annotation properly like: MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:MyAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease]