# set coordinated of user location programmatically Xcode/Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

i am implementing an iOS application, and i want to set the user location programmatically. i have tried mapView.

> ```
>         mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latFloat, longFloat);
> ```

it tells that this is assigned to readonly property.

so how to assign the user location programmatically? aiming to show the blue point at a custom location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can't.  That property is for the user location, not an arbitrary point.  You should use MKAnnotation and it's associated classes for such a thing.  If you wanted to do a kind of point with a pulsing circle similar to the user location you may find an custom MKOverlay more suitable.  Be warned though multiple MKOverlays *will* crash your application in which case you want to draw the many things in one MKOverlayView using an MKOverlayPathView.

** As an aside, for testing in the simulator you can pass in an arbitrary list of points to the simulator that it will feed into the app as the userlocation.  This is solely for testing various map related code though and won't actually help or work in 'the real world'**

Something like, assuming 'annotations' is an NSMutableArray containing your annotations.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV 
    viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

  MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
  MKPinAnnotationColor pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
  if([annotations lastObject] == annotation)  
  {
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"LastLocationIdentifier"];
    pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
  }
  else
  {
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"PreviousLocationIdentifier"];
  }

  pinView.pinColor = pinColor;

  return pinView;
}
```

I'm not currently in a position to test this but will do later.

Comment: thanks for you comment...
what do i have is a map, and i have an array of objects that is filled by coordinates, lat and long, and i am dropping multiple annotations on the map... the last dropped pin is the last location of the user. So that what i want is to add the blue circle to the last location. i tried changing the color of the last pins i couldn't. here is my past thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369712/multiple-annotation-color/12369885#comment16636904_12369885
or what do you suggest??

Comment: works perfect. thanks a lot, but only one thing changed is that is is zooming to last, while before all of the annotations wee appear on the map...
thanks again

Comment: So does it only display one annotation now?  I'm not quite following I think.

Comment: i made some changes for a method that i have called flyto and now everything is working the way i want...
thanks a lot dude :)

Answer (score 1):

Use .gpx file to set the user location as you wanted.

Steps:

- Press Commd + N
- Go to Resource
- Then select gpx
- enter a name for it and choose the location to save
- .gpx file is a XML formatted file.
- In the lat = "37.331705" lon = "-122.030237", change this lat and lon values according to your own location.
- Don't forget to click on simulate location button, if you've selected "DOn't simulate my location". then, change it to your saved location name..

for more details, check this out------

http://plainoldstan.blogspot.cz/2011/08/on-gpx-files-for-xcode-42.html

(just forget to add)Also in your viewDidLoad method, don't forget to add-

yourMapView.showuserslocation = YES;